Movie (drama/thriller) about privatization of water?
I remember that once I saw a movie on board a flight (about 5-10 years ago).  The movie was a drama/thriller/sci-fi (i.e. not a documentary), and the story line is set upon a conspiracy to privatize water.  
Roughly I recall something like this (but I could be wrong, because I was very sleepy on that flight ...) The bad guys (a corporation) want to privatize water.  They have a plot to make any public water not drinkable.  And then they would be able to make mega bucks by selling some alternative water that only they can provide.  Something along this line ...
Somehow I could not find any Internet trace about this movie.
Can anyone recall this movie?  The movie seems to be an american movie.

I have not seen this film, but the following film is about water ownership: Young Ones (2014) - post apocalypse, science-fiction, killing for water...There are a lot films about water that are much older like China Town, Promise Land, or The Grapes of Wrath, but that doesn't meet your criteria.

Thanks for trying.  Regarding Quantum of Solace, I don't recall the movie is a Bond movie.  Regarding Young Ones, it is too new and it also is not the movie in my mind.

Hi. There are quite a few movies involving intentionally contaminated water, so can you help us narrow this down in any way? For instance, what makes you think it was sci-fi? And do you remember other plot points? The actors or characters?

@Walt -- I recall that the conspiracy involves some sort of technologies (i.e. the bad guys were not simply poisoning the water).  That's why I tend to think this was a sci-fi movie.  If you can list the names of the movies in your mind, I can go check them out one by one and see if one clicks.  Thanks!

Judging from the time-frame and other details I'm wondering if this isn't Quantum of Solace (2008) which is, of course, a Bond movie with Daniel Craig.
At least part of the plot is...

The following day, Bond and Camille survey Quantum's intended land acquisition by air; their plane is shot down by a Bolivian fighter aircraft. They skydive into a sinkhole, and discover Quantum is damming Bolivia's supply of fresh water to create a monopoly.
At an eco hotel in the desert, Greene tells Medrano that now he controls the majority of Bolivia's water supply, Medrano must accept a new contract that makes Greene Planet Bolivia's sole water utility company at significantly higher rates. 
Wikipedia

